# Chosen select box with multiple selected values on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to select multiple values on page load, but it only selects the last value on the array. Take a look at the code

```
jQuery("#language").chosen();
var str = '12,24,36';
var languageArray = str.split(',');
 for (var i = 0; i < languageArray.length; i++) {
     jQuery("#language").val(languageArray[i]);
     jQuery("#language").trigger("liszt:updated");
 }
```

I get only 36 selected on page load, is there anything wrong with the js ?

Here is the HTML for the select

```
<select name="language[]" id="language" data-placeholder="Choose Language..."  multiple="multiple">
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select multiple options in a multi-value select box by passing an array to the `val()` method.

### Example

#### Markup

```
<select name="language" id="language" data-placeholder="Choose Language..."  multiple="multiple">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
</select>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var str = 'en,de';
jQuery("#language").val(str.split(','));
```

And here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvfv3/) for funsies.

Answer (score 1):

you could set the `selected` property of matched option element. hope it would help.

```
var values = ['1', '2', '4'];
$('#languages').find('option').filter(function (idx, option) {
    if($.inArray(option.value, values) !== -1) {
        return option;
    }
}).prop('selected', 'true');
```